# Trouble setting up R, OpenMP and glmmTMB

Tags: r, parallel-processing, ubuntu-20.04, glmmtmb

I am looking at a couple of complex models that seem to need a lot of computational power. I am currently using the R package "glmmTMB" to account for spatio-temporal autocorrelation and random effects. In theory, glmmTMB should be able to run much faster using parallelization: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/parallel.html

> If your OS supports OpenMP parallelization and R was installed using
> OpenMP, glmmTMB will automatically pick up the OpenMP flags from R’s
> Makevars and compile the C++ model with OpenMP support. If the flag is
> not available, then the model will be compiled with serial
> optimization only.

Instead of running these models on my personal maschine, I decided to set up a virtual maschine in a HPC environment. How can I install R using OpenMP on Ubuntu 20.04? I couldn't find anything on this topic.